# Could not find ActionBar views when using lib MaterialMenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

The problem is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find ActionBar views"

but the getActionBar() method is working well.

This is the code reported contain error:

```
mainMaterialMenuIcon = new MaterialMenuIcon(MainActivity.this, Color.WHITE, Stroke.THIN);
```